# Remove dots between whitespaces

Tags: python, string

I am trying to remove dots between two blanks and print one whitespace

`re.sub(r'\s(\.){1,}\s', ' ', T)`

So.. if i have **"This is . my car"** the output is **"This is my car"**

Comment: string.replace(" . "," ")? Also, your code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two approaches you can take:

### Split, strip and merge

This has the advantage of not relying on regular expressions, but I'm not sure how it compares performance wise:

```py
src = "This is . my car"
fixed = " ".join(segment.strip() for segment in src.split(" . "))
print(fixed)
```

This works regardless of the number of spaces around dots, but will not affect anything that has a dot without two spaces around it.

### Using re.sub

Regular expressions are a power tool. I like them, and find them to be immensely worth mastering, but some developers avoid them. Try something like:

```py
import re

src = "This is . my car"
fixed = re.sub(r'\s+\.\s+', ' ', src)
print(fixed)
```

Essentially, this regex matches a sequence of one or more whitespace, then literal dot, then one or more whitespace, and replaces it all with a single space. Capturing is not required.

One suggestion is, when re-using the same regular expression many times (e.g. if you need to process many many strings with the same regex), you should use [compiled `re` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects) and not call `re.sub` again and again for each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is really to just do a direct string `replace`:

```py
string = "This is . my car"
print(string.replace(' . ', ' ')) # This is my car
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a string, you can call the `split()` method using the dot as delimiter. This will return a list of string that can be reattached to each other.

```
str = "My string with . a dot"
list_str = str.split(".")
```

Now `list_str` contains `["My string with ", " a dot"]`

Edit: by the way, to concatenate the strings contained in `list_str` you can simply do `list_str[0] + list_str[1]`. If you want to get rid of white spaces at the beginning and end of the substrings, you can call `str.split()` to remove both of the spaces, `str.rstrip()` and `str.lstrip()` to remove spaces only on the right (end) or left (beginning) of the string.